# How to best protect 12V from voltage transient spikes?

Tags: protection, circuit-protection, esd, surge-protection, transient-suppression

I am building an AC power supply and I decided to put digital current and voltage panel meters into it.

I have an issue where whenever my main contactor engages and disengages, there is a transient induced into the 12 DC powering the panel meters, causing them to break.

I've tried shielded twisted cables (shielded to ground,) ferrites, and recently TVS diodes. I've had the most success with TVS diodes, however my power supply is powered through two GFCI breakers (one from the mains, and one in the power supply) and if there's a large enough transient passing through the TVS diode, it will trigger the GFCI breaker.

I've been trying to add resistance behind the diode but it has not been very successful so far.

Is there a strategy I'm missing here?

Maybe something like if you could store the transient energy into a capacitor and slowly discharge it into the ground without tripping the GFCI?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Protection Circuit?]

Comment: Can you add a complete scheatic? It will be helpful in finding a solution for your problem.

Comment: Pi filter on your 12 V line? Local decoupling capacitors everywhere?

Comment: At least we need a rough representation of your setup. A schematic with some circuit blocks. Noise problems can be sneaky and ephemeral, it is impossible to track them down without having the circuitry in mind.

Comment: Here is a basic schematic, https://imgur.com/hQjxEwS